# Raspberry Pi 3 possible OS installations

Tags: ubuntu

I have installed Raspbian OS in a 32 GB memory card and am using it in Raspberry Pi 3. Is it possible to put Ubuntu OS on the same memory card and use it on the RPI 3?

Comment: Ahem: https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-install-multiple-oses-on-a-single-sd-card-for-raspberry-pi/

Answer (score 2):

If you need to ask then for you it is not possible. If you use a multiboot manager like NOOBS, PINN or Berryboot you have to decide upfront what OS flavours you want to install. Adding a second or third OS after the initial setup is either a) not possible or b) exceedingly complex with a deep understanding of filesystem partitioning and boot managers needed (not for the faint hearted).

SDCards are cheap. Just swap it out when you want to try a new OS.

I've done all of that stuff in the past and found its usually not worth the effort. My eighteen Raspberries all run plain old Raspbian. Two boot from a hard drive, three boot from USB sticks, two have the rootfs on a hard drive and the rest boot from SDCards.